# How do I set up a facet search with a many to many relationship using Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, many-to-many, faceted-search, sunspot

I haven't implemented a search feature before and feel a bit stuck. I have a Sunspot search feature which finds results based on keywords - this works great - but I now want to implement the multi select facet feature, but I can't even seem to figure out how to set-up a basic facet search.

I have a many to many relationship (in rails not in real life):

Class People has_many :skills, :through => experience (and vice versa etc)

```
Class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, :through => experience

  searchable do
    text :first_name, :surname
  end
end
```

In the controller

```
@search = Sunspot.search(People)
   facet :skill_ids
end
```

This is the basic example I can't get working. It generates this error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for People with name 'skill_ids'
```

**How do I create the link to :skill_ids**

I think I must be missing some reference in the model - but no examples I can find do reference the Ids of a relationship. Most of the examples I found use columns that are already in that model when using the facet functionality.

- How can I get the basic implementation working?
- How would I use this in the view - do I have to call hits.facet and iterate over the skills? What would the code look like to display this?
- How would I select multiple facets to search by?
- Should I put this in the community wiki?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Anything you want to filter, facet, or order on, Sunspot needs to know about. So in your model:

```
searchable do
  text :first_name, :surname
  integer :skill_ids, :multiple => true, :references => Skill
end
```

Your #search call in your controller looks right. In your view, you'd do something along these lines:

```
- @search.facet(:skill_ids).rows.each do |row|
  = row.instance.name
```

`row.instance` will return the instance of Skill that the row's value refers to (that's what the `:references` option is doing in the `searchable` definition).

I'm not sure what you mean by "select multiple facets to search by" -- one can generate multiple facets (which give users *choices* for further search refinement) by calling the `facet` method multiple times in a search; and you can then use their facet choices with scope restrictions using the `with` method, which you can also call as many times as you'd like.

Speaking of wikis, most of this information is available (with more explanation) in the Sunspot wiki:

- http://wiki.github.com/outoftime/sunspot/

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find a reference to the :multiple part in the wiki or anywhere else - must have been using the wrong search terms or something. You got the right idea of what I meant by "select multiple facets to search by" - put another way: filtering by multiple selections.

The wiki now makes sense to me with a working demo to test on! I will try adding in the filtering functionality next: would I be right to think I can create a link_to and pass in parameters for additional facets, or is that a long way around?

Thanks again!