# Rails Sunspot/Solr: Ordering on multiple-value field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm trying to do a priority "order by" on a  multiple-value field using solr - any idea how I can accomplish the below?

```
searchable do
  integer :skill_ids, :multiple => true
end

def self.filter_using_solr(opts={})
  Sunspot.search(JobApplication) do |s|
    opts[:order_skill_ids].each do |skill_id|
        s.order_by(:skill_ids, skill_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following exception "skill_ids cannot be used for ordering because it is a multiple-value field" - but not sure on the alternate path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is Solr's [faceted search](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Drilling-down-with-facets).

There are several posts on this subject including [How do I set up a facet search with a many to many relationship using Sunspot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522231/how-do-i-set-up-a-facet-search-with-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-sunspot)

Naturally, the [Solr docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams) are also useful.